# Build failed in Android Studio 3.1, gradle 4.4 class signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, libgdx, android-studio-3.1

I'm making a project in Android Studio 3.1 with libgdx and i can't build my project because it says:

```
class "org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.IDEA$Mappings"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

But i don't use "bouncycastle" or something
I checked a lot pages and topics about this problem but i didn't find any solutions for this. Also i haven't any jar files and i never tried to sign something, i'm only trying to build my project
Please help me guys, i really stuck at it

Answer (score 1):

Update: Java 10.0.2 was having issues with GDX 1.9.8 so I downgraded to Java 8 and everything is working as expected. If you installed the latest Java 10, uninstall and download and install the java 8 version.

---

Old evaluation:

I've recently encountered this issue with android 3.1.4 and a current version of libgdx(jar downloaded on 09/xx/2018).

Environment: Freshly installed Windows 7 Ultimate + sp1 + convenience rollup, gdx-setup.jar(September xx, 2018), + Android Studio 3.1.4(clean install), java 10.0.2.

Problem reproduced: gdx-setup.jar with my updated "build-tools" + "api" produced a project, but the project did not compile in Android Studio and produced the error originally posted.

Process: gdx-setup.jar with its default build-tools(27.0.3) and default api(27) will produce an error about incorrect api 28 > 27, which may not be relevant to some, but new installations of Android Studio 3.1.4 may encounter this. Used Android studio sdk-manager(tools tab) and downloaded 27.0.3 build-tools and sdk-tools (make sure the "Show package details" is checked for visibility). After installing the above and rerunning gdx-set.jar on defaults, I was able to produce the project and even compile/run on Android studio.

Temporary Solution for GDX(September 2018): Ensure Android Studio has: build-tools 27.0.3 + sdk-tools 27, and create the gdx project using defaults for tools (No to both prompts when creating gdx project).

Comment: I don't know if you still log in, but your solution for `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.IDEA$Mappings` was to downgrade to Java 8? I have 8 as my default, and even uninstalled 11, but I'm still getting this error when building an APK.  :/